# changing iframe url changes parent window url

Tags: javascript, iframe

i'm using following page to display content of a url in a iframe and changing it based on input value .

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeUrl()
{
 var url=document.getElementById('browseurl').value;
 if(url!="")
 {
   if(url.indexOf("http")==-1)
   {
    url="http://"+url;
   }
   document.getElementById('browserWnd').src=url;
 }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <div >
   <span>Url</span> 
   <input id="browseurl" name="browseurl" type='textbox' />
   <input id="browse" type='button' value="changeurl" onclick="changeUrl()" />
 </div>

<iframe id="browserWnd" src="http://www.coolmath.com/" height="700" width="625"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

my problem is browsing some inner pages of an url loaded in iframe ***changes the parent window url*** instead of loading in iframe ...

for ex *http://www.coolmath.com/* load in iframe but while browsing some links loads the entire page in parent window.

Answer (score 2):

From www.coolmath.com:

```
if (window.self != window.top) ...
```

meaning the site activly escapes being framed.

Comment: but following also do the same without self or top. http://www.woodlands-junior.kent.sch.uk/maths/

Comment: @Paniyar The link you provided *does* have `self` and `top`. The code is: 

`<script language="JavaSCript">if (top.location != location) top.location.href = location.href;</script>`

Answer (score 2):

You may notice that even something like this `<iframe src='http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-fraction-splat/index.html'></iframe>` results in the same. This is a technique called [frame-busting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller). It's in their page's code:

```
<script>
<!-- Hide Script
 if (top.location != self.location) {
   top.location = self.location
 }
//End Hide Script-->
</script>
```

If you have a server, that can respond with a `HTTP/1.1 204 No Content` header, you may be able to "deactivate" this frame buster as described [here](http://coderrr.wordpress.com/2009/02/13/preventing-frame-busting-and-click-jacking-ui-redressing/).

Comment: I can't tell you how long I have been searching for this.  Another check though might be `if(top != self)`.  I was looking in some old code that kept popping the page out of the my `iframe` but didn't know what was causing it.  Thank you.