# changing iframe url changes parent window url Blocked a frame with origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use this code

```
<script>
  <!-- Hide Script
    if (top.location != self.location) {
     top.location = self.location
    }
  //End Hide Script -->
</script>
```

However recently I get such errors in the chrome console and the code stopped working

> (index):15 Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin 'http://preview.themeforest.net' from frame with URL 'http://site.test'. The frame attempting navigation is targeting its top-level window, but is neither same-origin with its target nor has it received a user gesture. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5851021045661696.
>
> (index):21 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replace' on 'Location': The current window does not have permission to navigate the target frame to 'http://site.test''.

In Firefox and Opera this code works. In Chrome it does not work.

How to fix these errors?

It's a bit like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8573735/changing-iframe-url-changes-parent-window-url)

Answer (score 7):

Please check the same origin policy: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

The reason for that error is that you violate that policy.

The only way I know to avoid this is to setup the iframe sandboxed (kinda restricted) with the allow-top-navigation flag.

```
<iframe src="demo_iframe_sandbox.htm" sandbox="allow-top-navigation"></iframe>
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp

Check the restrictions and see if that solution fits for you.

Comment: can I add it in site.test this child iframe sandbox? via js

here iframe code

<iframe class="full-screen-preview__frame" src="site.test " name="preview-frame" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" data-view="fullScreenPreview">
 </iframe>